# How to create a responsive popup using fancybox 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, fancybox-2

I've created a simple popup using fancy box2. It's looking good on desktop site.
When I see this pop up on a mobile it's all stretch to the mobile and looks tiny. I need to show this to fit into the mobile display when I open the page on mobile. 
How can I do that? Do I want to use any other plugin together with fancy box or can I do that by JS/ CSS? Please do suggestions.... 
[demo](http://cyberactions.com/popup-fancy/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("document").ready(function(){
            $("a.button").fancybox();
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        #popup { display: none; width: 100%;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="login_popup">
        <a class="button" href="#popup" >Login</a>
            <div id="popup">
                <a href="#" class="close">CLOSE</a>
                <form>
                    <P><span class="title">Username</span> <input name="" type="text" /></P>
                    <P><span class="title">Password</span> <input name="" type="password" /></P>
                    <P><input name="" type="button" value="Login" /></P>
                </form>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try setting `autoSize` to `false` so it will stretch to the size on your css declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under `<head>` tag of your code add:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: If you are creating responsive website i.e. one site for all screen sizes. Then this meta tag should be in head section. Put it in head so I can see in demo.

Comment: Don't see narrow on desktop, it is the size of contents of your form.

Comment: but I do not set any width.. how can I show that fit to the display size?

Comment: you want form to be wider? or what. For that set css of #popup like `#popup{min-width: 300px;}`

Comment: ok.. its creating a vertical bar.. we leave that for now.. but as u see a scroll bar on desktop I do not see the scroll bar on mobile.. and I could not scroll it on mobile.. but it scrolls in ipad with not showing the scroll bars.. how can I enable scrolling on mobile... I put scrolling: 'yes'.. but seems not working on mobile..

Comment: On my mobile it is scrolling. mobile browsers generally don't show prominent scrollbar but it is scrolling with me.

Comment: ha? on my 7" samsung it's scrolling.. on my samsung mobile it's not scrolling.. weird... u checked in which mobile?

Comment: Machine is never important; checked on Chrome Mobile browser

Comment: Scrolling on android's default browser. Just no scroll bar. It is on browser to show scrollbar or not.

Comment: in Ipad and smasung tab NO scroll bars.. but I am able to scroll by swapping on the form.. but on normal samsung phone, on a default browser of samsung phone NO scroll bars and unable to scroll..

Comment: So that may be issue with those phone browsers. Some thing that can't be fixed. Or may be bug in fancybox.